# $_FILES["file"]["size"] returning 0?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload something using PHP and set a limit on the total size that I allow to be uploaded. I want to limit my uploads to 2MB but for some reason whenever I try to check with an if statement like this:

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152))
```

A file that is large (such as a 7mb file) will pass through the if statement because for whatever reason if I print `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`, it will return 0, instead of the proper number of bytes. If I try to upload something that is smaller, like 342kb the `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` will return the proper size.

Is there anyway to get `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` to actually hold the proper size of the file? Otherwise I do not know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Which is the limit of uploadable data in your php.ini? Are you sure that file you tried to upload (7MB) has really been uploaded correctly? I think it's not...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the max upload size of a file is set by php.ini, the php config file. If the file is larger than that limit, it will never even be uploaded to begin with, which is why you would get a file size of 0.

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES);` ;) and check error reporting...

Comment: You are right, the 7mb file is not uploaded correctly. I get a return code 1 because php.ini has a limit of 2MB. That is why I am trying to write the if statement, but the if statement does not work.

EDIT: For some reason, a file that is larger than 2MB will actually make the connection and begin to upload, it just fails after it uploads the file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A file which aborts for any reason (upload failed, exceeds limits, etc...) will show as size 0

You have to check for upload SUCCESS before you do ANYTHING with the rest of th eupload data:

```
if(array_key_exists('file', $_FILES)){
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       echo 'upload was successful';
    } else {
       die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
    }
}
```

The error codes are defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). In your case, if you've hardcoded a 2meg limit and someone uploads a 2.1 meg file, then the error code would be UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE (aka `2`), which is "exceeds limit set in .ini file".

Comment: Error code is 0, size is also 0... how do we get around that one?

Comment: It really just depends on how you want your application to react because you can have a case such as described earlier by @Deji where error code and size would return 0. I think one example of this happening is if you open a zipped file in Windows Explorer and try drag and dropping a file from the file list presented to you to certain javascript file uploaders

Answer (score 4):

```
if( $_FILES['file']['size'] && $_FILES['file']['size'] < (2<<20))
```

Try that.

<< is bitwise shift operator, decimal 2 is binary "10", then add 20 zeros.

Comment: very nice way, although you could've explain the code - not everyone knows how to use binary shift to do power calculations

Answer (score 1):

How I supposed in my previous comment, your problem is that limit of uploadable file in php.ini is less than 7MB.
So you could try to use

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0 && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
```

Consider that if you put your limit (in php.ini) to 2MB, that check could be easily written as

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

check for any errors prior to uploading. These will often give away what the problem is.
Create a class to return any code error and use it for uploading files.

```
 class UploadException extends Exception
{
public function __construct($code) {
    $message = $this->codeToMessage($code);
    parent::__construct($message, $code);
}

private function codeToMessage($code)
{
    switch ($code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $message = "No file was uploaded";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            $message = "Missing a temporary folder";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            $message = "Failed to write file to disk";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            $message = "File upload stopped by extension";
            break;

        default:
            $message = "Unknown upload error";
            break;
    }
    return $message;
  }
}
```

Now check whether the upload was success before you do anything with the file.
If it's NOT uploaded successfully, it'll result in a error which will tell you what's wrong.

This way, instead of having to waste your time on guessing what the error code could mean or having to look it up all the time, your own made up error message will return the message corresponding with the error code.

```
   if ($_FILES['realFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'no problems encountered. File was uploaded with success';
    } else {
        throw new UploadException($_FILES['realFile']['error']);
    }
```