# File upload results in file size 0 and error code 0

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to upload an image to a php script. I have a, non-persistent, bug that results in some of the images uploaded has a file size of 0. I have tried to print the _FILES array to my log file, and it shows the error code being 0, which should be ok.

These lines:

```
foreach($_FILES['image_file'] as $key => $val){
      error_log(date('j/n/o H:i:s')." ". $key ." => ".$val. "\n", 3,$log_path);
    }
```

Give me these in the log file:

1. 3/10/2012 12:12:54 name => 59175248636.jpg
2. 3/10/2012 12:12:54 type => image/jpeg
3. 3/10/2012 12:12:54 tmp_name => C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php411F.tmp
4. 3/10/2012 12:12:54 error => 0
5. 3/10/2012 12:12:54 size => 0

As can be read from the log file, this script runs on a Windows machine, of which I have limited knowledge. I have already changed the post_max_size to 10M, as well as upload_max_size to 10M in the php.ini.

I am flabbergasted about this issue. When I test from my own devices, it works fine, but for some reason, when my testers try it out, it fails.

Comment: the images are storing in file system or not??

Comment: Well. That's actually a good question. As I'm deploying this on a server that I don't access to, my only means of testing this, is by using move_uploaded_file. This method returns true and the file is saved (to the dir I want) with filsize 0.

Comment: Don't you have to use something like temp_size to get to the filesize?

Comment: Ignore my comment - it's incorrect as far as I can remember

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Try this:

I think you may need to change $_FILES['file'] to $_FILES['image_file'] to work with your setup. I have left it as below for ease of reading...

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0){

   ... upload was successful ...

}elseif($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $_FILES['file']['size'] == 0){

   die("Upload failed, random upload issue... please try again);
   // change this error to something more useful... (leave this error in for testing)

}else {

   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);

}
```

This doesn't solve the random filesize issue, but it will allow your code / process to continue. Treat it as a failed upload and tell the user to try again...

Used code from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959615/filesfilesize-returning-0) posted by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)

Comment: Hi Chris. Yeah, I've seen that post, but as you can see in the log I've posted, the error code is 0, which according to http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php means that the upload was successful.

Comment: Does the filesize exceed the Max filesize?? I think that will set the filesize to zero even though it has uploaded successfully. - You could test this by trying a file over 10mb maybe

Comment: I tried that, but I just get the following message: Notice: Undefined index: image_file in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\iPost\receiver.php on line 35. So I'm guessing that its not the size that's the problem.

Comment: Possible more things to try here: http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/

Comment: Nah, Only the jpg type. It's the only filetype I will accept.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll have a look and come back.

Comment: Another idea: do you have something that checks for 'JPG','JPEG','jpeg'. If so - maybe that check may be causing the issue. Just an idea

Comment: Hmm. I don't have any checks for jpgs, so that can't be it. I also tried to change the php.ini according to the link, but to no avail.

Comment: I have edited the code above, give it a try. It doesn't prevent the issue from occurring, BUT if it does, the code will catch the error and inform the user or whatever you want it to do...

Answer (score 0):

Since I run into this from time to time, I guess I'll just post one reason this could happen: Size and error 0 can occur if you try drag and dropping a file from a Windows Explorer view of a zipped file (double click a zipped file and it opens up just like a folder) to your uploader. I use DropzoneJS a lot and by default, it processes these files immediately and pushes it to my server, which ends up seeing a 0 bytes file with no file upload errors. So if your users are doing the above, that could be the reason why you end up with such files.