# PHP file upload always returns MIME type "inode/x-empty"

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

So I have a function that uploads terms & conditions to a folder. I fetch the extension and MIME type of the file and check if they are valid. As of recently, all files I upload return `$_FILES[$key]['size']` as `0` while the files on the local disk do have a file size. When I check the MIME type using the following script, it always returns `inode/x-empty`.

```
$finfo    = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileType = finfo_file($finfo, $file['tmp_name']); // Returns 'inode/x-empty'
$expl     = explode('.', $file['name']);
$fileExt  = end($expl);
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening as it didn't a couple of months back. I've never seen this happen before either.

Below is an example of the $_FILES output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => audite_marlow_logo.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcHbiLN
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 0
)
```

The server's php.ini is more than capable of handling any files I upload. The `post_max_size` is set to an insane `128M`.

All the files I upload return with an `error` with an integer value of `0`.

I am honestly lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: quick question... this can happen if the file size is greater than your php.ini `post_max_size` value. any chance this is the cause? highly unlikely if it is just a small jpeg file, but worth asking just to make sure it is not the obvious culprit.

Comment: @Abela: The file in my example is 76kb in size. I can upload images on another page much larger than this.

Comment: Okie, figured that was the case. Might suggest giving this a go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959615/filesfilesize-returning-0  something is erroring out, code on that page should help diagnose it.

Comment: @Abela: Every file I upload returns and error code of 0.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$_FILES['file']['error']` is not returning any results? ref: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @Abela: Multiple times, yes. It just returns without any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120431/discussion-between-audite-marlow-and-abela).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem, which also started suddenly out of nowhere.

Comment: I did not find a solution for this. It stopped as sudden as it had started for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because, you ask finfo (phpcHbiLN) of a tmp file name however `$_FILE['type']` check the finfo of the uploaded file (`audite_marlow_logo.jpg`). 
In an other way, finfo need an absolut path so make sur `tmp/phpcHbiLN` is an absolut path.

`inode/x-empty` signify the file you are trying to check is empty make sur your file is readeable with simple check `is_readable()`, `file_exists()` or `is_file()`.