# File upload error in ios devices when uploading pdf

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, file-upload

I have a form with a file upload field. It works fine, but sometimes I can't open submitted `.pdf` files. 
I dumped the `$_FILES['file']` I had something like this :

```
'name' => 'takhtak.pdf',
'type' => 'application/pdf',
'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php5NWFIj',
'error' => 0,
'size' => 0,
```

I have submited the same `.pdf` file with the same device and only 1 of 50 it fails.I have uploaded the same file, and it only sometimes returns size = 0,in common the form work normally.
Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_FILES\["file"\]\["size"\] returning 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959615/filesfilesize-returning-0)

Comment: thanks but my question is different, as I said I have uploaded the same file, and it sometimes returns size = 0, If there is any conflict with the file size, it will return 0 every time I submit the form.

Comment: OK - so an intermittent issue with the same file on the same device. Do you have any more information that might help us? For instance, how large are the files? Do failed uploads take longer than successful ones? What do you have `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` set to? Also, does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707230/file-upload-results-in-file-size-0-and-error-code-0 match your problem?

Comment: No, that question doesn't match my issue. I have not any problem with images. The images are submitted well. I have a problem only with the files which are located under the 'Browse' button on my phone(like .xls, .pdf). The files from the 'Photo Library' are submitted without any bug. And only when upload files like .xls and .pdf I have an rarely issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently and reached here. It seems to be a long running IOS bug (or spec) since 2016. The File object we take from <input type=’file’ onChange=… seems to be destroyed after 90 seconds or so (can be random) by OS. It could be because of data security - I have no idea why. Uploaded file at the API has zero byte size though other properties such as filename are all OK. This can happen not only PDF but jpg, png, etc.

The File class has arrayBuffer() and I tried. It works fine in my test environment so far. I’m not 100% confidence if bad side effect etc. Simply create a new File object that won’t be destroyed.

```
async onChange(e: any) {
    const file: File = e.currentTarget.files[0] as File;
    const buf = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const clone = new File([buf], file.name, { type: file.type });
    this.setState({ file: clone });    
}
```

The clone object is the one valid until leaving the page.
new File([file]... doesn't work, it is reference copy.